# How to pass the number values from angular to webapi

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

this is my code
**model.ts**

```
export class Customer {
    customer_id :number
    firstname : string
    lastname : string
    email : string
    telephone : number
    password : string
}
```

**component.ts**

```
resetForm(form? : NgForm)
  {
    if(form!=null)
          form.reset();
      this.customerService.selectedCustomer=
      {       
        customer_id : null,
        firstname :'',
        lastname :'',
        email :'',

        password:'',
        telephone: //i want to pass 10 digit no here

      }
```

I want to pass telephone number to webapi form angular 5.how to achieve it

Comment: simple like this `telephone = 1234567890`?

Comment: I Don't want to hard code the number.I want to use dynamic.I have a customer registration form each customer must enter the  number

Comment: So bind the value to some variable or using form , SIMPLE !!

Answer (score 0):

Change your model class to below

```
export class Customer {
customer_id :number
firstname : string
lastname : string
email : string
telephone : string
password : string }
```

You can pass it as string value to controller.

Then in future even if the format of number changes it would be easy to post.

```
resetForm(form? : NgForm)
{
  if(form!=null)
      form.reset();
  this.customerService.selectedCustomer=
   {       
    customer_id : null,
    firstname :'',
    lastname :'',
    email :'',
    password:'',
    telephone: ''
  }
```

Comment: In Webapi the telephone data type was Phonenumber.When i use string in angular and pass the value it return a null value to controller.

Comment: What is `Phonenumber` type? is it a custom data type?